# VBA Vertical scrollbar thumb size

Tags: excel, form-control, vba

I have a form where controls are dynamically created, the scrollbar included, with

```
Set theScroll = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.ScrollBar.1", "sc1", True)
```

but I'm having difficulty resizing or changing the scrollbar thumb size other than the min value, it doesn't seem to have an event or function for resize.

I've also tried using

```
Userform1.ScrollBars = fmScrollBarsVertical
```

but I can't move it anywhere around the form since I need to have the said scrollbar slightly off of center of the form.